# How to make an if statement using data from a written file

Tags: python, arrays, file, if-statement

I am currently trying to now utilize an if statement that checks the score values set in a file that was read earlier as a par value. I am currently unsure of how to have the data be read as specific integers as those values were previously converted to string values in an earlier portion of the assignment. Where would I want to initially start?

I have currently managed to have the program read the .txt files made initially in the beginning part, however, I currently am unsure of how to handle this initial program in regards to converting the final numerical values back to normal, nor am I sure how to get it to properly cycle to check each specific record's final data piece.

This is the data the program pulls from:

```
Andrew,Marks,11.2,72.0
Betty,Franks,12.8,89.0
Connie,William,14.6,92.0
Donny,Ventura,9.9,78.0
Ernie,Turner,10.1,81.0
Fred,Smythe,8.1,75.0
Greg,Tucker,7.2,72.0
Henry,Zebulon,8.3,83.0
Ian,Fleming,4.2,72.0
Jan,Holden,7.7,84.0
Kit,Possum,7.9,79.0
Landy,Bern,10.3,93.0
Mona,Docker,11.3,98.0
Kevin,Niles,7.1,80.0
Pam,Stiles,10.9,87.0
Russ,Hunt,5.6,73.0
```

The Program designed to pull the data from the file and run it in the if statement is this:

```
infile = open('golf.txt', 'r')
golf = infile.readlines()

for elements in golf:
    int(golf[elements[3]])
    if golf[elements[3]] > 80:
        print(elements, 'Score: Over Par')
    elif golf[elements[3]] == 80:
        print(elements, 'Score: At Par')
    elif golf[elements[3]] < 80:
        print(elements, 'Score: Under Par')

infile.close()
```

I was expecting it to print the individual lists, alongside stating the score was "over par", "under par", or "At Par" dependent on what the final value in each list inside the external list, however I receive this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joelc/PycharmProjects/Project2/File/JoelLab5Pt2.py", line 7, in <module>
    int(golf[elements[3]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Don’t use golf[elements[3]]. Start with e=int(elements[3]) and carry on with if e > 80: etc

Comment: You can not directly convert a string to int, especially if the string has float value, first convert it to float and then int.

Comment: what do you expect `elements` contains, in `for elements in golf:`?

Comment: Your issue appears to be the handling of lists, not type conversions. What do you think `golf[elements[3]]` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split each line to get the comma-separated values.

```
with open('golf.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        values = line.split(',')
        score = float(values[3])
        if score > 80:
            print(line, 'Score: Over Par')
        ...
```

Using the `with` statement makes sure the file gets closed. Otherwise, it's recommended to use exception handling to open and close files. `with` takes care of closing the file for you as soon as control exits out of the with block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each line on the commas and then convert element 3 to a float.

```
infile = open('golf.txt', 'r')
for line in infile:
    elements = line.split(‘,’)
    e = float(elements[3])
    if e > 80:
        # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

### Consider using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org):

- Once the data is in a dataframe, easily compute other metrics or plot the data
- Given the data shown, in a `.csv`, and with no headers
- Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create a new column for par
- I don't know what the 3rd column should be, so I just left it as index 2.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, names=['first_name', 'last_name', 2, 'score'])

first_name last_name     2  score
    Andrew     Marks  11.2   72.0
     Betty    Franks  12.8   89.0
    Connie   William  14.6   92.0
     Donny   Ventura   9.9   78.0

# make a par column
criteria = [df['score'] < 80, df['score'] == 80, df['score'] > 80]
values = ['Under Par', 'At Par', 'Over Par']

df['par'] = np.select(criteria, values)

first_name last_name     2  score        par
    Andrew     Marks  11.2   72.0  Under Par
     Betty    Franks  12.8   89.0   Over Par
    Connie   William  14.6   92.0   Over Par
     Donny   Ventura   9.9   78.0  Under Par

# save it
df.to_csv('my_file.csv', index=False)
```